# Merge NCBI and Ensembl data

Tags: phylogenetics, genomes, blast, ncbi

Apologies if this is a really naive question, but I cannot figure out how to do this easily. [Here](https://www.biostars.org/p/7568/) is a related post regarding the best method to find orthologous genes of a species.

---

Let's say I have a protein alignment downloaded from Ensembl (coming, for instance, from [this Ensembl tree](http://www.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Gene/Compara_Tree?collapse=none;db=core;g=ENSG00000101440;r=20:34194569-34269344)).

This gene is present in some other "NCBI species" that I would like to include in my tree (for instance, *[Stegastes partitus](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=stegastes%20partitus)*, with available genome and present in the NCBI database but **NOT** in the Ensembl database). Indeed, if I **manually** blastp *asip* protein sequence of *D. rerio* (extracted from my Ensembl multifasta protein alignment) onto *nr* database parsed for *S. partitus*, I find [this sequence](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/657574989?report=genbank&log$=protalign&blast_rank=1&RID=VP54WBWH014), corresponding to the first blast hit. Perfect! And I can **manually** append it to my initial protein tree.

Where the problem starts is that I don't have *one* gene and *one* NCBI species but **many** of them (let's say `p` genes and `n` NCBI species). I already have an Ensembl protein multifasta file for each of my `p` genes.

My question is: is there an easy way to append to each of my `p` multifasta files the corresponding homologous protein sequence(s) for the `n` "NCBI species"?

Thanks for any insight!